# Multiple files not appearing on server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when I'm trying to upload files to my server. I have done this many times before so I'm not sure why this is happening now. Nothing has changed to my knowledge.

What's happening is the following:

- submit the 1, 2, etc... files through the uploader
- check the headers it clearly shows **N** amount of files.
- test php file and put the line `print_r($_FILES)`; it will show only one file, the last one on the file stack specifically.

Just for reference I am using the jquery plugin Bootstrap File Input by Krajee.

**file input plugin docs**
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url : '../assets/server/trade/submitTradeForm.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : data,
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(response){
        if(!response.errors){
            if($('#images').get(0).files.length > 0){
                $('#images').on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data, previewId, index){
                    //$('#tradeForm')[0].reset();
                    bootbox.alert(data.response.success_message);
                });
                $('#images').on('filelock', function(event, filestack, extraData){
                    extraData['trade_form__id'] = response.trade_form__id;
                });
                $('#images').fileinput('upload');
            }else{
                bootbox.alert(response.success_message);
            }
        }else{
            bootbox.alert(response.error_message);
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $names = array();
    $files = array();
    $mime_types = array();
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $name){
        array_push($names, $name);
    }
    foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $temp){
        array_push($files, $temp);
    }
    foreach($_FILES['file']['type'] as $type){
        array_push($mime_types, $type);
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you ahead of time for any and all assistance!

Comment: you sure you declared your file inputs in your form as an array? I.e.`name="file[]"`

Comment: that was it -.- man I suck at my job some days. Is it Friday yet? XD

Comment: I had a feeling that's what it was. ;-) yes, it is Friday!! woohoo!!

Comment: well if you want to put it as an answer go ahead and I'll shoot you some points for your time. Thank you as usual @Fred-ii-. You comment on a lot of my posts, and I do learn a lot from you it's much appreciated. You're awesome!

Comment: You're welcome Mark. I'll formulate something a bit more informative ;-) give me a minute or so. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the form wasn't posted along with how your file inputs are named, the `name` attribute for each file requires it to be accessed via an array.

For example:

`<input type="file" name="file[]">` with the square brackets.

The brackets declares/signifies it as an array.

Therefore, PHP took in a file alright, only one and is the last one used because of the missing array declaration.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php